# Create CDBcriteria in yii

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-events

How to create cdbcriteria fo the query like :

```
select * from table_name where 'profile_type'='*'OR 'profile_type'=$usertype  AND 'location'='*'OR 'location'=$country
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass condition as below.

Note: This is one of the method. Not an ultimate solution.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition  = "(profile_type ='*' OR profile_type = $usertype)  AND (location ='*' OR location = $country)";

$model = Model_name::model()->findAll($criteria );
```

Comment: Dont you think you should wrap the condition in double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

you can try sth like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition  = "(profile_type='*' OR profile_type=:prof ) AND 
                         (location='*' OR  location=:loc ) ";

$criteria->params = array(':prof' => $usertype, ':loc' => $country);

$model = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria );
```